# Object of class stdClass could not be converted

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Object of class stdClass could not be converted `how can i fix this Error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Movie;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Livewire\Component;

class MovieList extends Component
{

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.movie-list',[
            'movies' => DB::table('movies')->where('user_id', 1)->paginate(10),
        ]);
    }
}
```

movie view blade

```
@foreach( $movies as $movie )

     <a href="{{ route('movies.show', $movie) }}" > {{ $movie->title }} </a>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by using Eloquent query instead. Since you are using a raw expression, some methods may not be available.

Try with

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Movie;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Livewire\Component;

class MovieList extends Component
{

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.movie-list',[
            'movies' => Movie::where('user_id', 1)->paginate(10),
        ]);
    }
}
```